# wp media regenerate says "no regeneration needed" whe that's no the case

Tags: post-thumbnails, media, wp-cli

I'm trying to generate thumbnails for a PDF attachment. Right now in the uploads/ folder there is only the PDF file, no image thumbnails related to it.

But when I run the regeneration with :

```
wp media regenerate 1188810 --image_size=portrait_medium
```

it shows this message :

```
Found 1 image to regenerate.
1/1 No "portrait_medium" thumbnail regeneration needed for "Products catalog" (ID 1188810).
```

I dont understand why it says no thumbnail regeneration is needed when that's not the case.

My custom image sizes are defined like this in `functions.php` :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mwm_custom_image_sizes' );
function mwm_custom_image_sizes() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'portrait_medium', 200, 286, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
}
```

Comment: Turns out PDF thumbnail sizes are handled differently, I ended up solving the issue using the  `fallback_intermediate_image_sizes` filter. See here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/415634/how-can-i-add-custom-sizes-for-pdf-thumbnails-generation

Answer (score 0):

### Caveat:

Note that this solution ***may introduce a security flaw in your site***. Use it with extreme caution.

On my installation, I got a warning when I tried to regenerate PDF thumbnails:

> attempt to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy `PDF'

...which, upon searching for that string, appears to indicate that `imagemagick` (which does WordPress's image handling) won't process PDF files.

[A comment on a support thread](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/60580) had this to say:

> Parsing PDF was disabled[1] in /etc/ImageMagick-7/policy.xml due to its inherent insecurity. The same thing did Ubuntu and perhaps more distros will follow as this is recommendation from security researchers.
>
> You may enable it locally by removing 'PDF' from below line:
> `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="{PS,PS2,PS3,EPS,PDF,XPS}" />`
>
> [1] https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/59778

If I removed `PDF` from the `rights="none"` `pattern`, I was able to successfully regenerate the image(s) for the PDF file.

### Caveat

Note that this solution ***may introduce a security flaw in your site***. Use it with extreme caution.

Comment: My ImageMagick policy is already patched like this. When I upload a new PDF, it creates the 3 default sizes successfully, it's the custom image sizes that seem to be ignored.