# How can I add custom sizes for PDF thumbnails generation?

Tags: uploads, media-library, thumbnails, pdf

I define custom image sizes in my theme like this :

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mwm_custom_image_sizes' );
function mwm_custom_image_sizes() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'portrait_medium', 200, 286, array( 'center', 'top' ) );
    etc...
}
```

When I upload an image, the defaut *and* custom image sizes are created as expected :

[image]

But when I upload a PDF file, only the default image sizes for the cover are generated :

[image: jj]

How can I tell Wordpress to generate PDF cover images for all image sizes that are defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the [`fallback_intermediate_image_sizes`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4ad3cad2e0d9369d96f04837babe6270a1423487/src/wp-admin/includes/image.php#L594-L594) filter within `wp_generate_attachment_metadata()`:

```
 **
 * Filters the image sizes generated for non-image mime types.
 *
 * @since 4.7.0
 *
 * @param string[] $fallback_sizes An array of image size names.
 * @param array    $metadata       Current attachment metadata.
 */
$fallback_sizes = apply_filters( 'fallback_intermediate_image_sizes', $fallback_sizes, $metadata );
```

where the default sizes are:

```
$fallback_sizes = array(
    'thumbnail',
    'medium',
    'large',
);
```

See core ticket [#39231](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39231).

Comment: Thanks, as you suggested adding that filter and passing my custome sizes to the `$fallback_sizes` array did the trick.

Comment: Good to hear it worked for you mike23

Comment: Thank you, @birgire @mike23 - I had the same question around adding custom image sizes for PDF thumbnails (i.e. non-image mime types) and I used the `fallback_intermediate_image_sizes` in this way:

`add_filter( 'fallback_intermediate_image_sizes', 'add_custom_sizes_for_posters', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_sizes_for_posters( $fallback_sizes, $metadata ) {
 return array( 'poster-thumb', 'poster-large' );
}`

With the "poster-" names corresponding to custom image sizes I added by `add_image_size`